# How do I tell my internal IP to send to my external IP?

Tags: dns, minecraft

I have set up everything necessary for a minecraft server, I have a DNS client with ddclient which is sent from helloworld.dyndns.org to my external ip

I have an static internal IP but there is a missing link between the internal and the external IP?

It should go helloworld.dyndns.org > 90.201.0.137 >! 192.168.0.5

The '>!' is the missing link (I think).

I have configured the settings in the router config for it to go through the port 25565 and also in the minecraft config file. Do I need to specify the port I want to use anywhere else? Or is that step complete and there is something else missing? 
Help!!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When testing the connection out, be sure to enter the server and port number.

Minecraft server must be running and listening on 25565.  You need to also go into your router's configuration, look for a Port Forwarding section and forward incoming requests to 25565 to the machine  running your server.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell your router to forward incoming connection attempts to the desired port number to the IP address of the machine you want to use as a server. The option will be in your router settings somewhere .. sometimes it is referred to as "DMZ" (de-militarized zone) settings, though on home routers the concept is not really the same as the DMZ used on corporate networks.